# Unable to load jquery CDN

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery CDN for JavaScript will give

> $ is not defined error.

and

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

this console error occurs

Can't load jQuery?

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </ script>
```

I used to load a CDN

```
<script src = "js / default.js"> </ script>
```

I linked it with my folder.
I tried changing the order.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> My name's lEEGANG</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script> <!--js파일 연결-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

**default.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".all").on("click", function() {

    $(".nav").addClass("on");

    });
});
```

default.js all code is an ERROR

> ERROR:'$' is not defined.[no-undef]

and

> ERROR:'document' is not defined.[no-undef]

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // rest of your code })

Comment: I've tried, no...ㅠ

Comment: You need this for cdn `<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: It is cross origin issue only.

Comment: Still not. Why is that?

Comment: Look at this [jquery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: I just copied and used it but the error still occurs

Comment: look at the browser console what error do you receive?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) occus !

Comment: Have you try this : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I Tried your code found no issue try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="all">Level One</li>
    <li>Level One</li>
    <li>Level One</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".all").on("click", function() {

      $(".nav").addClass("on");

      });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Note: Check the path properly. You are using document.ready function that is fine, still try once script after body tag like this.

Comment: But the problem is that the jQuery file is not loaded

Comment: Oh thank you!! It works well, but why should I do this?

Comment: Why shouldn't I make a .js file of the file?

Comment: You can make js file. I given you this code just for test to check it work or not on your site, Now as you said its working that mean their is no issue with jquery library file and your js code, now the issue might be in the path of your own custom js file. So please check with that and try to add it after body tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:-**

```css
.on{color:red;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="all">Level One</li>
    <li>Level One</li>
    <li>Level One</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on("click", ".all", function() {
      alert();
      $(".nav").addClass("on");
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```